# What is the best way to get a sample k8 yaml to edit as per requirement?

Tags: kubernetes

In declarative approach , what is the best way to get a default/sample yaml file which we can edit on vi as per our requirement , do we need to copy it everytime from k8 doc ?

Answer (score 3):

Some resource samples can be created with `kubectl create <resource type> <resource name> --dry-run=client -o yaml`. To see which resource can be created run `kubectl create --help`.

For example, to create a deployment named `demo` with `nginx` image, run:

```
kubectl --namespace=default create deploy demo --image=nginx --port=80 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

It generates:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Another example with Ingress. Write YAML definition to `demo-ingress.yaml`

```
kubectl create ingress demo --rule="foo.com/api=api-svc:8080,tls=my-cert" --dry-run=client -o yaml > demo-ingress.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, k8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/) is the best place to start with a default yaml file for the required setup as its up-to-date and you are sure that it works without any surprises for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

The VSCode Kubernetes plugin includes scaffolds for the major object types. I'm guessing there are similar plugins for other editors.